# RailwayJS vs Geddy vs Express vs Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, node.js, frameworks, express, railway.js

Whats the opinion of experts about these frameworks. I'm developing a large application and would like a good framework, but I'm struggling with the amount and variety that exists (it sucks!). Why in Node that is javascript, have so much influence of Rails way (Geddy, RailwayJS - "Sinatra influence", "RoR influence"? Frustration?

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of application are you developing? What do you want the JS to do?

Comment: It's will be a medium port webapp with active access to DB (mongodb), thanks @FloppyDisk

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of applications you are building. Expressjs is more of a sinatra framework, while railway is more of a ruby on rails implementation. Expressjs gives you the basic foundation but let's you decide how you want to go from there. Railway.js is more of a fully stacked framework giving you the mvc pattern, orm, built in support for csrf, file uploads, and lots more.

For a big application you could either build on top of express and implement a somewhat similar mvc solution, including some orm modules or things you need. You would have to spend more time implementing the core of your application instead of the app it self.

On the other hand you can go with rails and with a bit of learning curve start building your app immediately.